# How to exclude a maven module from dependency inheritance?

Tags: maven, module, dependencies, pom.xml

```
platform
|_frontend
|_registry
|_shared
```

Given this maven structure where **platform** is the root-pom and the others are modules.
I want **frontend** and **registry** to be have the same dependencies but these should **not**  be included or inherited to the **shared** module.

What I cannot do is to declare the dependencies within the **platform** because it will give these to all modules. Only adding the dependencies by hand to **frontend** and **registry** is a working solution but kind of code/config duplication.

Isn't there a way to have some kind of *dependency sets* defined which I can assign to modules explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a separate project only containing a POM. You add all the dependencies from your "dependency set" to this POM. Then you define a dependency on this POM in `frontend` and `registry`.